# I am trying to get json data from: http://crmfrdev.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/Cordova_Select.jsp Then I wish to display this data in a table

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
  <script>
     $(function() {
       var entries = [];
       var dmJSON = "http://crmfrdev.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/Cordova_Select.jsp?callback=?";
       $.getJSON( dmJSON, function(data) {
         $.each(data.entries, function(i, f) {
           var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.Store_Media_Id + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Store_Name + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Store_ID + "</td>"  + "</tr>"$(tblRow).appendTo("#entrydata tbody");
         });
        });
      });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="profile">
        <table id= "entrydata" border="1">
          <thead>
             <th>STORE MEDIA ID</th><th>STORE NAME</th><th>STORE ID</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody></tbody>
       </table>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What's the problem? Also: Your response does not have `entries` key.

Comment: The problem is that wishes are usually made truth by genie :)

Comment: you have a little mistake  `$.each(data, function(i, f) {});` and not `data.entries`

Comment: when i am using text file, i am able to retrieve data but when i using url...it's not working with in same code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, ensure that you allow cross origin when the engine renders your page (see this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

Second, you code is broken. Have this:

```
 $(function() {
   var entries = [];
   var dmJSON = "http://crmfrdev.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/Cordova_Select.jsp?callback=?";
   $.getJSON(dmJSON, function(data) {
       $.each(data, function(i, f) {
       var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.Store_Media_Id + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Store_Name + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Store_ID + "</td>" + "</tr>"
  $(tblRow).appendTo("#entrydata tbody");
     });
  });
});
```

Comment: you copied without even checking the syntax, there is a missing semicolon `;` in theis line `s var tblRow =...`

Comment: it is not my question, I only wanted to say that you have to check the syntax before posting an answer.

Comment: For your information, in javascript, going to the next line is interpreted as putting ;. Therefore, it does not matter. This is not C#!

Comment: posted code is working fine when i m using text file but it is not working when i m using url - http://crmfrdev.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/Cordova_Select.jsp